# What kind of space is this, and how does one rigorously treat it?

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-topology, compactification

Consider $k$ congruent copies of the geodesic compactification of $X:=\Bbb R\times \Bbb H^2.$ Denote the $k$ congruent copies as $X_k$ for $k\in \Bbb N.$ Let $p_k^-$ and $p_k^+$ represent the antipodal singular points of $X_k.$ Embed $X_k$ for all $k,$ into the interior of a sphere, (where all $p_k^+$ and $p_k^-$ lie on the surface of said sphere).

> Q: What kind of space is this? And how does one rigorously treat it?

The real line in each copy of $X,$ acts as the diameter of the sphere, connecting the corresponding $p^+$ and $p^-.$ I am having trouble thinking about and defining this rigorously. It's like there are all these real line diameters that pass through the center of the sphere, reminding me of $\Bbb R P^2,$ but that's ignoring the hyperbolic directions of each copy of $X.$

*Geodesic Compactification:*

[image]

*Product Compactification:*

[image]

Comment: What are antipodal singular points of $X_k$? Is the geodesic compactification you are referring to where points on the compactification  are geodesic rays emanating from a point which are bounded distance from each other?

Comment: I'm trying to find some more info, but, the geodesic compactification of $X$ is related to the product compactification by blowing up $p^+$ and $p^-$ into singular circles, and likewise to transfer back, you can blow down the singular circles into points. The product compactification can be viewed as a cylinder with the caps of the cylinder being the singular circles and the real line orthogonal to the hyperbolic disk(s). I found a diagram which I hope is helpful.

Comment: So the boundary you are considering is a sphere, and you want to embed that sphere into a sphere? I am not really sure what you are trying to rigorously treat. Perhaps you want to look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov_boundary#Visual_boundary_of_CAT(0)_space) Where is this geodesic boundary defined? It looks like you are taking a join of the two boundaries I guess.

Comment: It's a little hard to understand exactly what you are asking for. But, for rigorous treatment you should need two things: basic constructions of topology such as product spaces and quotient spaces, all of which can be found in a basic topology book such as Munkres' "Topology"; and constructions of the boundary compactifications of $\mathbb H^2$ and other spaces such as $\mathbb H^2 \times \mathbb R$, such as can be found in elementary books on hyperbolic geometry, with some further information in the Bridson-Haefliger book "metric spaces of nonpositive curvature".

Comment: @PaulPlummer Thanks for that link. Let me edit my question to be more specific: I would like to rigorously be able to define the sphere, so that would amount to being able to write down an equation that describes all these antipodal points $p^+$ and $p^-$ being the same distance from each other. The main point of issue for me is that I don't know how to deal with the sphere having a diameter as the real line with a point at $p^-$ at neg. infty and $p^+$ pos. infty! I'm used to the diameter being a simple number like $1.$ The Gromov Boundary seems right on target though. I will read about that

Comment: What equations are you using just for the boundary of $\mathbb{R}$? (You already run into the same problem you seem to be having) How about for $\mathbb{H}^2$? Are you wanting these equations to have some sort of compatibility with the underlying metric spaces? Also I recommend looking at Bridson-Haefliger book (Ch II.8).